# regular expression understanding

Tags: regex

Can anybody help me decoding this RegExp?

```
/^(.+)\s{1}\((.*)\)$/
```

Comment: https://regex101.com

Comment: This likely has nothing to do with Ruby since regex is a DSL.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//` is simply placeholder for regexp, `^(.+)\s{1}\((.*)\)$` remains

`^` means start of the string, `$` is end of the string, `(.+)\s{1}\((.*)\)` remains

`(.+)` is first group of items, it matches any chars (if there's no chars the `+` will fail, because it means "give me 1 or more characters"), `\s{1}\((.*)\)` still remains

`\s{1}` means "give me any exactly one whitespace", `\((.*)\)` still remains

`\(` and `\)` means that you are encoded brackets to use their literal form, because simply using `()` is as a match group, `(.*)` left

`(.*)` is the same as `(.+)`, but here also zero characters will match, since `*` means "give me anything, even nothing"

eg. `Patryk (patnowak)` will pass and `Pat Nowak` won't

Answer (score 0):

/^(.+)\s{1}((.*))$/

Would match something like: Hello (1id93;)
To go step by step, since this is what a regex does:

/ - opens the regex

^ - matches at the start

( - opens a matching group, that will be returned in: $1

.+ - matches any character one or more times

) - closes the matching group

\s - matches an empty space

{1} - exactly one of them 

( - matches a ( the backslash makes sure it matches the ( character
(.*) - again matches anything 0 or several times and returns matching group $2
) - matches a )
$ - marks the end of the regex.
/ - closes the regex

Comment: Actually, the backslashes in front of the brackets are missing now...this edit needs editing...